# UX for faceted filtering?

Tags: forms, filter, faceted-search

The Swedish website "*Prisjakt*" - a website used for price comparisons - has a very nice set of form elements that dynamically update to indicate matching elements based on applied filters.

See link and/or attached image:
http://www.prisjakt.nu/kategori.php?k=168&o=lokal_rank&rev=1#prodlista

**Are there alternative (and even better) methods for doing what is shown in the image?** (keywords: "filters with indicators")

[image: form]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much information you need.
As I work on data analysis, users need detailed information.
If you do so, you should look at **Google refine** tool which offers the most efficient interface for advanced facets.

In comparison with Prisjakt I see many benefits :

- Bar charts show values with and without other facets
- Limits are clearly shown under the chart (easy to edit)
- Slider and chart are merged in one UI component

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like their solution in general, though I believe it's somewhat messy or "too much information in a single bite".

The first solution that comes into mind when thinking of form components, for me, is **jQuery UI**, and maybe a specific example that might suit what you're looking for is this one: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

That being said, the dynamic updating and is something that I think escapes the scope of this question, but it should be quite easy to replicate with jQuery and AJAX.